# payload-file-path issue in slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.24.0

Tags: github-actions, slack-api

I am trying to write a workflow.yml for payload-file-path in slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.24.0 Github actions. I am using payload-file-path instead of payload. While I tried to run the workflow file I am getting this error

**Error Message -**

```
Run Tests
Error: The payload-file-path may be incorrect. Failed to load the file: .github/resources/payload-slack-content.json
```

**Workflow file code -**

```
       - name: Slack Notification
         id: slackPayloadFile
         uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.24.0
         with:
          payload-file-path: ./.github/resources/payload-slack-content.json
```

**Complete logs -**

```
Run slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.24.0
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/actions/actions/.github/resources/payload-slack-content.json'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/home/runner/work/actions/actions/.github/resources/payload-slack-content.json'
}
Error: Error: The payload-file-path may be incorrect. Failed to load the file: .github/resources/payload-slack-content.json
```

Any help on this please? I am using this technique of slack-api github actions - https://github.com/slackapi/slack-github-action#technique-3-slack-incoming-webhook

Tried changing path formats but didn't work

Comment: Please add the rest of your workflow in your question. Either the file path is incorrect or you are missing the checkout step.

Comment: My silly mistake, checking out repo worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> checking out repo worked.

That is illustrated with [`slackapi/slack-github-action` issue 104](https://github.com/slackapi/slack-github-action/issues/104#issuecomment-1174805877)

> Try to checkout the repository at the beginning of Action

In your case, your workflow file should be:

```yaml
name: Slack Notification Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  notify:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        
      - name: Slack Notification
        id: slackPayloadFile
        uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.24.0
        with:
          payload-file-path: ./.github/resources/payload-slack-content.json
```